# How to perform load test of login functionality using 5 logins at a time

Tags: java, selenium, load-testing

```
public class Login {

public WebDriver driver ;

@Test(invocationCount = 20, threadPoolSize = 5)
public void GmailLogin() throws InterruptedException {
WebDriver driver = LoadTest.getInstance().getDriver();  
driver.get("https://tst-oec-ebooking.azurewebsites.net/");    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div/input")).sendKeys("mad@dayrep.com");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(6000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Password\"]")).sendKeys("Pass@123");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login_submit\"]")).click();
Thread.sleep(1500);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

@BeforeMethod
public void setup(){
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\CIPL0564\\D Drive\\Software\\geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown(){
LoadTest.getInstance().removeDriver();
}
}
```

By Executing the above code,the application is running 20 times with same login.But i need to run the application with 5 login credentials each time and if possible with different browsers also.Kindly suggest the modifications i need to do.

Comment: How many times is it running with current configuration. Is it one by one twenty times or 5 at once four times?

Comment: I would suggest to use JMeter for these kind of scenarios

Comment: 5 at once four times.I need that to login with different login Id's each time

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing a static method to get the username/password (This is just `pseudo code`)

```
public class CredentialHelper {
private static int counter = 0;
private static List<MyGmailCredential> myGmailCredentials = [5 credentials];
public static synchronized MyGmailCredential getCredential() {
    MyGmailCredential currentCred = CredentialHelper.myGmailCredentials[counter%5];
    CredentialHelper.counter++;
    return currenCred;
}
}
```

Use in your class

```
public class Login {

public WebDriver driver ;

@Test(invocationCount = 20, threadPoolSize = 5)
public void GmailLogin() throws InterruptedException {
WebDriver driver = LoadTest.getInstance().getDriver();  
driver.get("https://tst-oec-ebooking.azurewebsites.net/");    
MyGmailCredential myGmailCredential = CredentialHelper.getCredential();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div/input")).sendKeys(myGmailCredential.getUserName());
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(6000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Password\"]")).sendKeys(myGmailCredential.getPassword());
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login_submit\"]")).click();
Thread.sleep(1500);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

@BeforeMethod
public void setup(){
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\CIPL0564\\D Drive\\Software\\geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown(){
LoadTest.getInstance().removeDriver();
}
}
```